# how to set value in javascript div tag

Tags: javascript

how to set value using javascript i want  set value onclick function  + 20  current points please help
my code not working please help me this

> ony use javascript not jquery

```
<div class="score">
    <input id="txtscore"   value= "0"class="width150" type="text"    /> 
</div>
<div class="box1">
    <a href='' onclick='check()'>check</a>
</div>

function check(){ 
    var getvalue =   document.getElementById('txtscore').value;
     getvalue = getvalue + 20;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get your element and set the new value

- Convert the entered value to number to get the right result.
- You need to validate the entered value before any calculation.
- To avoid a refresh in your page, use this: `href='#'` or bind a click event to prevent the default behavior.

```js
function check() {
  var textscore = document.getElementById('txtscore');
  textscore.value = Number(textscore.value) + 20;
}
```

```html
<div class="score">
  <input id="txtscore" value="0" class="width150" type="text" /> </div>
<div class="box1">
  <a href='#' onclick='check()'>check</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the value to a number otherwise you will concatenate a string, you can also use button instead of a link, if you use a link by default the page will refresh...

```js
function check(){ 
          var getvalue =   document.getElementById('txtscore').value;
                      getvalue = parseInt(getvalue) + 20;
          document.getElementById('txtscore').value=getvalue;
        }
```

```html
<div class="score">
                    <input id="txtscore"   value= "0"class="width150" type="number"    /> </div>
   <div class="box1">
            <button onclick='check()'>check</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: While not necessary it's often a good idea to add `parseInt`s radix value.

Comment: its working but  after click textbox auto refresh , value automatically 0 :(